# Missing com.exacttarget.fuelsdk.internal package

Tags: marketing-cloud, fuel-sdk

I grabbed the FuelSDK from github. I added the missing libraries (gson, cxf, and log4j) to the project, but seems that I am missing the com.exacttarget.fuelsdk.internal package. Is this built off the WSDL somehow?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. You need to run `mvn generate-sources`.